# Summing the values of an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble figuring out the elegant way to add an array of hashes

```
[{:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3},{:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3},{:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3}]
```

should return

```
[{:a=>3,:b=>6,:c=>9}]
```

I know it would probably involve mapping/reducing, but I can't figure out the right syntax, doesn't help that ruby-doc dot org doesn't match my version

I am using 1.8.7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
array.inject{|x,y| x.merge(y){|_,a,b| a + b}}
```

(verified on Ruby 1.8.7)

Comment: This is pretty cool, although I don't know why the merge works without injecting an empty hash...

Comment: @hurikhan77 the first inject takes place initialized with the first item of array -- not with an empty element.

Comment: @Peter what does the underscore do as the first block parameter for merge?

Comment: @Beerlington, it's just a variable I don't want to use. It's actually a Python convention to name it that. (The three parameters passed to the block are key, x value, y value.)

Comment: @Peter i think the underscore is more a haskell convention (from its pattern matching) which was also taken by python...

Comment: @hurikhan77 ah, interesting - thanks. haskell's on the list to add to the repertoire at some point.

Comment: @Berlington: Running Ruby with warnings (`ruby -w`) would warn you that a variable is unused, unless it is `_` (or starts with `_` in upcoming 2.0.0). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified-in-ruby