# Where and how is the _ (underscore) variable specified?

Tags: ruby

Most are aware of `_`’s special meaning in IRB as a holder for last return value, but that is *not* what I'm asking about here.

Instead, I’m asking about `_` when used as a variable name in plain-old-Ruby-code. Here it appears to have special behavior, akin to a “don't care variable” (à la [Prolog](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#dontcare)). Here are some useful examples illustrating its unique behavior:

```
lambda { |x, x| 42 }            # SyntaxError: duplicated argument name
lambda { |_, _| 42 }.call(4, 2) # => 42
lambda { |_, _| 42 }.call(_, _) # NameError: undefined local variable or method `_'
lambda { |_| _ + 1 }.call(42)   # => 43
lambda { |_, _| _ }.call(4, 2)  # 1.8.7: => 2
                                # 1.9.3: => 4
_ = 42
_ * 100         # => 4200
_, _ = 4, 2; _  # => 2
```

These were all run in Ruby directly (with `puts`s added in)—not IRB—to avoid conflicting with its additional functionality.

This is all a result of my own experimentation though, as I cannot find any documentation on this behavior anywhere (admittedly it's not the easiest thing to search for). Ultimately, I'm curious how all of this works internally so I can better understand exactly what is special about `_`. So I’m asking for references to documentation, and, preferably, the Ruby source code (and perhaps [RubySpec](http://rubyspec.org/)) that reveal how `_` behaves in Ruby.

<sub>*Note: most of this arose out of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557485/hash-into-grouped-array/9557589#comment12116685_9557589) with [@Niklas B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/916657/niklas-b)*</sub>

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is some special handling in the source to suppress the "duplicate argument name" error. The error message only appears in `shadowing_lvar_gen` inside `parse.y`, [the 1.9.3 version looks like this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/parse.y#L8415):

```
static ID
shadowing_lvar_gen(struct parser_params *parser, ID name)
{
    if (idUScore == name) return name;
    /* ... */
```

and `idUScore` is [defined in `id.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/id.c#L51) like this:

```
REGISTER_SYMID(idUScore, "_");
```

You'll see similar special handling in [`warn_unused_var`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/parse.y#L9113):

```
static void
warn_unused_var(struct parser_params *parser, struct local_vars *local)
{
    /* ... */
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
        if (!v[i] || (u[i] & LVAR_USED)) continue;
        if (idUScore == v[i]) continue;
        rb_compile_warn(ruby_sourcefile, (int)u[i], "assigned but unused variable - %s", rb_id2name(v[i]));
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the warning is suppressed on the second line of the `for` loop.

The only special handling of `_` that I could find in the 1.9.3 source is above: the duplicate name error is suppressed and the unused variable warning is suppressed. Other than those two things, `_` is just a plain old variable like any other. I don't know of any documentation about the (minor) specialness of `_`.

In Ruby 2.0, the `idUScore == v[i]` test in [`warn_unused_var`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/parse.y#L9456) is replaced with a call to `is_private_local_id`:

```
if (is_private_local_id(v[i])) continue;
rb_warn4S(ruby_sourcefile, (int)u[i], "assigned but unused variable - %s", rb_id2name(v[i]));
```

and [`is_private_local_id`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/parse.y#L8606) suppresses warnings for variables that begin with `_`:

```
if (name == idUScore) return 1;
/* ... */
return RSTRING_PTR(s)[0] == '_';
```

rather than just `_` itself. So 2.0 loosens things up a bit.

Comment: I wonder if the difference in behavior of `lambda { |_, _| _ }.call(4, 2)` between 1.8 & 1.9 is just an unintentional side-effect then? As under "normal" circumstances where the variable name can't be duplicated the order in which they're assigned is inconsequential.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Yes, I think the "4 vs 2" issue is just an artifact of how 1.8 and 1.9 handle the stack. The only time it would be noticeable is `|_,_,...|` because the duplicate-error has been suppressed.

Comment: I wonder what made them include this, because this behavior doesn't seem to be specified nor documented anywhere. In other words, I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: A lot of people don't understand that tight language/library specs are often more about future-proofing than anything else. I haven't found anything in RubySpec about this stuff either.

Comment: @muistooshort Despite its apparent lack of existence in RubySpec, it seems to work the same in JRuby & Rubinius.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I wonder if everyone is reading each other's ChangeLogs behind our backs.

Comment: Nice find. I assumed it would be something simple like that, just suppressing the double parameter name error. Ruby really is a huge mess :D

Comment: @NiklasB.: Ruby has to get in line, every other language/interpreter/piece-of-software out there is already crowding the "big mess" line :)

Comment: @mu: Of course, I've yet to see a really clean implementation of an interpreted language (Lua comes close).

Answer (score 24):

`_` is a valid identifier. Identifiers can't just contain underscores, they can also *be* an underscore.

```
_ = o = Object.new
_.object_id == o.object_id
# => true
```

You can also use it as method names:

```
def o._; :_ end
o._
# => :_
```

Of course, it is not exactly a readable name, nor does it pass any information to the reader about what the variable refers to or what the method does.

`IRB`, in particular, sets `_` to the value of the last expression:

```
$ irb
> 'asd'
# => "asd"
> _
# => "asd"
```

As it is [in the source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb/context.rb#L167), it simply sets `_` to the last value:

```
@workspace.evaluate self, "_ = IRB.CurrentContext.last_value"
```

---

Did some repository exploring. Here's what I found:

On the last lines of the file [`id.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/id.c#L50), there is the call:

```
REGISTER_SYMID(idUScore, "_");
```

`grep`ing the source for `idUScore` gave me two seemingly relevant results:

- In the [`shadowing_lvar_gen` function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L8993)
- In the [`warn_unused_var` function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L9692)

`shadowing_lvar_gen` seems to be the mechanism through which the formal parameter of a block replaces a variable of the same name that exists in another scope. It is the function that seems to raise "duplicated argument name" `SyntaxError` and the "shadowing outer local variable" warning.

After `grep`ing the source for `shadowing_lvar_gen`, I found the following [on the changelog for Ruby 1.9.3](https://raw.github.com/ruby/ruby/trunk/doc/ChangeLog-1.9.3):

> Tue Dec 11 01:21:21 2007  Yukihiro Matsumoto
>
> - parse.y (shadowing_lvar_gen): no duplicate error for "_".

Which is likely to be the origin of [this line](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L8993):

```
if (idUScore == name) return name;
```

From this, I deduce that in a situation such as `proc { |_, _| :x }.call :a, :b`, one `_` variable simply shadows the other.

---

Here's [the commit in question](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/6bd65de203c7aaffc8d4241a771491356002ed75). It basically introduced these two lines:

```
if (!uscore) uscore = rb_intern("_");
if (uscore == name) return;
```

From a time when `idUScore` did not even exist, apparently.

Comment: This doesn't explain *at all* why `lambda { |_, _| 42 }` works while `lambda { |x, x| 42 }` doesn't.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, it appears you are right. `|_, _|` does work, but `|__, __|` doesn't. `_` does seem to have some special meaning, I will see if I can dig any information from the Ruby source.

Comment: By the way, your update, while informative, is not relevant as it only applies to IRb, which I specifically stated in my question I was not asking about.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I am reading the source code. It was just something I found on the way.

Comment: +1 for digging up the ChangeLog entry. Everyone should be a C hacker :)

Comment: @muistooshort The biggest problem is trying to find anything, I can understand most of the Ruby C code, I just can never find any of it unless it's documented. Also, `ack` is too smart for its own good and ignores the `.y` files.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I spent the first half of my programming career wading through hundreds of thousands of lines of undocumented C and C++ so I have some practice. I'm sure `ack` has a switch for that.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I actually didn't know about `ack`. I searched manually with plenty of `Ctrl` + `F` and the occasional `grep` to figure out where the functions were being used. I started with the files that seemed related to variables and identifiers. I got to a point where I started mentally expanding macros and then I found the entry on the changelog. :)

Comment: @muistooshort It does: `--all`, but I usually don't think to use it because it almost always searches just the right things.

Comment: +1 for the IRB source code.  IRB.CurrentContext.last_value is very interesting to know about, even if it's not relevant to the question as posed.  I ended up here from a google search about IRB underscore.