# How to find max value grouped by multiple keys in array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, max, uniq

Have data that has this kind of structure.  Will be in ascending order by 'c'.

```
[ { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  1, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  2, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  3, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  4, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  5, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  6, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  7, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  8, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  9, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 10, 'd' => '?' } ]
```

Want array of the max value of 'c' grouped by each unique combination of 'a' and 'b'.

```
[ { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  3, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  5, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  8, 'd' => '?' },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 10, 'd' => '?' } ]
```

The other keys need to be retained but are not otherwise related to the transformation. The best I could figure out so far is to reverse the array (thus descending ordered by 'c'), uniq by 'a' an 'b', and reverse array again.  But I am depending on the implementation of uniq_by always returning the first unique item found.  The specification doesn't say that, so I am worried about relying on that behavior since it could change in future versions.  Also wondering if this may be a really inefficient method.

```
@data.reverse!.uniq!{|record| [record['a'],record['b']]}.reverse!
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?  If you do have a better way, can you also please explain it instead of just giving me a super nasty one-liner that I may not be able to decipher.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's actually fairly easy:

```
a.group_by { |h| h.values_at("a", "b") }.map { |_, v| v.max_by { |h| h["c"] } }
```

Or with nicer formatting:

```
a.group_by do |h|
  h.values_at("a", "b") 
end.map do |_, v| 
  v.max_by { |h| h["c"] }
end
```

Explanation: first we use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to create a `Hash` with the combinations of  `"a"` and `"b"` (extracted with [Hash#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)) as the keys and all hashes with that combination as the values. We then map over this hash, ignore the keys and select the element with the maximum value for `"c"` from the array with [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Comment: Could you explain or give some reference to the meaning of `_` in block parameters?

Comment: @Flexoid: No special meaning, it's a parameter I don't care about and in a lot of languages it's customary to use an underscore for the name to signify that.

Comment: @steenslag Somehow the `"c"` became a `v` and it took me a second to figure out where I was being stupid ;-) Rereading my textual description helped, because I described it properly...

Comment: +1 for a very idiomatic solution, especially using `values_at` (which I would have failed to do). Though I did prefer @steenslag's `.last` instead of the `_,v` desplat. Or better yet, `a.group_by{...}.values.map{...}`

Comment: `_` does have a special meaning or at least [gets special treatment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9560198/479863) in some cases, the convention of using `_` as the *I don't care* parameter has hard-wired support in the interpreter. That's just nit picking a comment though :)