# Find highest values from associated array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have complex hash which looks like this

```
 @hash =  {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[], 5=>[], 6=>[], 7=>[], 8=>[], 9=>[], 10=>[], 11=>[], 12=>[[{"value"=>1.58, "title"=>"sun", "quantity" => 2}], [{"value"=>1.99, "title"=>"sophia", "quantity" => 5}], [{"value"=>6.30, "title"=>"roam", "quantity" => 15}], [{"value"=>3.981, "title"=>"jia, "quantity" => 4"}], 13 => [], 14 => [], 15 => []}
```

now I want to extract highest value along with associated title and quantity. index would 15 all the time.

for example the output should be

```
@hash = { value => 6.30, title => "roam", quantity => 15 }
```

I was searhcing some found this but did not make it work
reference link [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621721/how-to-find-max-value-grouped-by-multiple-keys-in-array-of-hashes)

help appreciated thanks

Comment: That hash isn't valid Ruby.

Comment: Maybe this: `@hash =  { 1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[], 5=>[], 6=>[], 7=>[], 8=>[], 9=>[], 10=>[], 11=>[], 12=>[[{"value"=>1.58, "title"=>"sun", "quantity" => 2}], [{"value"=>1.99, "title"=>"sophia", "quantity" => 5}], [{"value"=>6.30, "title"=>"roam", "quantity" => 15}], [{"value"=>3.981, "title"=>"jia", "quantity" => 4}]], 13 => [], 14 => [], 15 => []}` is you valid hash?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in the element's index, you could flatten the values and find the maximum one:

```
@hash =  {
  1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[], 5=>[], 6=>[], 7=>[], 8=>[], 9=>[],
  10=>[], 11=>[], 12=>[
    [{"value"=>1.58, "title"=>"sun", "quantity" => 2}],
    [{"value"=>1.99, "title"=>"sophia", "quantity" => 5}],
    [{"value"=>6.30, "title"=>"roam", "quantity" => 15}],
    [{"value"=>3.981, "title"=>"jia", "quantity" => "4"}]
  ],
  13 => [], 14 => [], 15 => []
}

@hash.values.flatten.max_by { |h| h["value"] }
#=> {"value"=>6.3, "title"=>"roam", "quantity"=>15}
```

Comment: Thanks , but I can not removed element's index ..is there any other way to solve this

Comment: @JNI_OnLoad What's your expected output?

Comment: I need only the highest value with assciated titles and quantity...I created this hash after filtering data for 1 days I hope now u get the point why I need element...

Comment: `6.3` is the highest *value*, `"roam"` is the associated *title* and `15` is the associated *quantity*. Please edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: That's what my code is returning, isn't it?

Comment: is it not giving error for array can not be compared with array ?

Comment: I've used the hash from falsetru's deleted answer, because your hash is invalid. See my update, there's no error.