# ruby: how to find non-unique elements in array and print each with number of occurrences?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have

```
a = ["a", "d", "c", "b", "b", "c", "c"]
```

and need to print something like (sorted descending by number of occurrences):

```
c:3
b:2
```

I understand first part (finding NON-unique) is:

```
b = a.select{ |e| a.count(e) > 1 }
=> ["c", "b", "b", "c", "c"]
```

or

```
puts b.select{|e, c| [e, a.count(e)] }.uniq

c
b
```

How to output each non-unique with number of occurrences sorted backwards?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
puts a.uniq.
       map { | e | [a.count(e), e] }.
       select { | c, _ | c > 1 }.
       sort.reverse.
       map { | c, e | "#{e}:#{c}" }
```

Comment: Very elegant! What does the '_' represent?  I've not seen that before.

Comment: @RichardBrown: A variable name that usually means unused.

Comment: You can also use underscores before unused variable names like `_temporary`. It serves the same purpose, but is a little more descriptive.

Comment: It's not the same purpose. `_` is a special variable name in Ruby, (inherited from Perl), that many methods write to by default. `_temporary` or any other variable starting with `_...` isn't in that category, and is a stand-alone and separate variable in the normal variable list.

Comment: I know `_` also serves a [special purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123494/whats-your-favourite-irb-trick/864710#864710), but in this instance, where it was used as an assigned but unused variable and in order to suppress the [warning ruby generates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified-in-ruby) in this instance, both options serve the same purpose I believe.

Answer (score 8):

The `group_by` method is used for this often:

```
a.group_by{ |i| i }
{
    "a" => [
        [0] "a"
    ],
    "d" => [
        [0] "d"
    ],
    "c" => [
        [0] "c",
        [1] "c",
        [2] "c"
    ],
    "b" => [
        [0] "b",
        [1] "b"
    ]
}
```

I like:

```
a.group_by{ |i| i }.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v), h| h[k] = v.size }
{
    "a" => 1,
    "d" => 1,
    "c" => 3,
    "b" => 2
}
```

Or:

```
Hash[a.group_by{ |i| i }.map{ |k,v| [k, v.size] }]
{
    "a" => 1,
    "d" => 1,
    "c" => 3,
    "b" => 2
}
```

One of those might scratch your itch. From there you can reduce the result using a little test:

```
Hash[a.group_by{ |i| i }.map{ |k,v| v.size > 1 && [k, v.size] }]
{
    "c" => 3,
    "b" => 2
}
```

If you just want to print the information use:

```
puts a.group_by{ |i| i }.map{ |k,v| "#{k}: #{v.size}" }
a: 1
d: 1
c: 3
b: 2
```

Comment: `group_by{|i| i}` can now be expressed as `group_by(&:itself)`

Answer (score 3):

From Ruby 2.7, you can utilise [`Enumerable#tally`](https://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable:tally) and numbered block arguments:

```rb
a = ["a", "d", "c", "b", "b", "c", "c"]
puts a.tally.filter { _2 > 1 }.sort_by { -_2 }.map &:first
```

Here, `Enumerable#tally` returns a hash like `{ 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, ... }`, which you then have to filter and sort. After sorting, the hash would've collapsed to a nested array, e.g. `[['b', 2], ...]`. The last step is to take the first argument of each array element, using `&:first`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
a.sort.chunk{|x| a.count(x)}.sort.reverse.each do |n, v|
  puts "#{v[0]}:#{n}" if n > 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally like this solution:

```
 a.inject({}) {|hash, val| hash[val] ||= 0; hash[val] += 1; hash}.
   reject{|key, value| value == 1}.sort.reverse.
   each_pair{|k,v| puts("#{k}:#{v}")}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a hash with `element => occurrences`:

```
b.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |hash, element|
  hash[element] += 1
  hash
end
```

Comment: The block could be put a little bit more elegantly: `hash.update(element => hash[element] + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
puts a.uniq.
     map { |e| a.count(e) > 1 ? [e, a.count(e)] : nil }.compact.
     sort { |a, b| b.last <=> a.last }
```

Comment: @undur_gongor I don't think it is, but it's the same as just having `a.uniq`... Any way, I kept uniq values as well in my code which makes it bad for the question and I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |memo,x| memo[x] += 1; memo } # Frequency count.
  .select { |_,count| count > 1 } # Choose non-unique items.
  .sort_by { |x| -x[1] } # Sort by number of occurrences descending.
# => [["c", 3], ["b", 2]]
```

Also:

```
a.group_by{|x|x}.map{|k,v|[k,v.size]}.select{|x|x[1]>1}.sort_by{|x|-x[1]}
# => [["c", 3], ["b", 2]]
```