# Is it a bad practice to use multiple assignment when only one variable will be used?

Tags: ruby

In the following example of multiple assignment, the variable `will_not_be_used` will not be referenced anywhere else. However, I personally find this approach to be simple and easy to understand.

Is this considered a bad practice?

```
useful,will_not_be_used = my_hash.detect { |key,value| value == "foo" }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's idiomatic to use an underscore (`_`) for throwaway values like that:

```
useful, _ = my_hash.detect { |key,value| value == "foo" }
```

**Update:** As pointed out by Jörg W Mittag in the comments below, Ruby itself understands `_` to be a throwaway variable: when run with warnings enabled, Ruby (at least MRI, possibly others) will warn about unused local variables unless they start with an underscore.

Comment: It's not just idiomatic, it's even encouraged by the execution engine: unused local variables trigger a warning, unless they start with an underscore.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Is it "starts with `_`" or [just `_` itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9560198/479863)?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks; I added that very useful information to my answer.

Comment: @muistooshort At least with MRI 2.0.0p195, it's "starts with `_`" and not just `_` itself, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Note that `_` is used by IRB and PRY to hold the results of the last expression. Just something to keep in mind if you're assigning to it explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, they changed it in 2.0, if you check `warn_unused_var` in the source you'll get to [`is_private_local_id`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/parse.y#L8606) and see the `RSTRING_PTR(s)[0] == '_'` test. 1.9.3 just checks for `_` in its [`warn_unused_var`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/parse.y#L9128).

Comment: Another difference is that, when you have multiple instances of it in an assignment like `_, foo, *_ = array`, it does not warn you.

Answer (score 1):

### Throw-Away Values

There's nothing inherently wrong with using multiple assignment to discard throw-away values, but it may not be as intention-revealing as other constructions. Depending on your data or its intended use, one of the following may be more verbose but semantically clearer:

```
my_hash = {bar: "foo", baz: "quux"}
# => {:bar=>"foo", :baz=>"quux"}

my_hash.rassoc('foo').first
# => :bar

my_hash.select { |k,v| v == "foo" }.keys.first
# => :bar

my_hash.map { |key, value| key if value == "foo" }.first
# => :bar
```

The use of [Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) may be driving the use of the discarded assignment, but there are certainly other use cases worth considering. For your specific example, though, it probably makes no difference.

Comment: I don't like using "_". It's too much like Perl to use a "magic" variable. And, I much prefer seeing `first` or `[0]`.