# extracting numbers from string without the use of regex in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
string = "12abc3 def*40"
```

How would I go about extracting 12, 3 and 40 from that string without the use of regex? Here's my method with the help of regex.

```
def numberExtraction(str)
    str_array = str.split(/\D/).delete_if {|char| char == ""}
    str_array.map(&:to_i)
end
```

Comment: I think the best way is to use a regex. I don't know if the `isdigit` functionality that C has exists in Ruby.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a regexp?

Comment: Use `/\D+/` instead of `/\D/`. Then you don't need to delete empty strings (which can be done by calling `delete_if(&:empty?)`), and all can be simplify to `str.split(/\D+/).map(&:to_i).compact`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Enumearble#chunk](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/chunk):

```
def extract_numbers(str)
  str.
    chars.
    chunk { |char| ('0'..'9').include? char }.
    select { |is_digit, _| is_digit }.
    map { |_, chars| chars.join }
end

extract_numbers("12abc3 def*40")
#=> ["12", "3", "40"]
```

Comment: What if "010" in the string ?

Comment: Your answer is beautiful, but I think you need `to_i` after `join`.

Comment: what is the function of the underscore "_" in map and select?

Comment: Underscore represents a parameter which we don't care about. See this question for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified-in-ruby

Comment: @user2684075 may we come to know why you don't want to use a regex? I am curious :)

Comment: That's a very good question. I like @p11y's solution, it is way more concise and readable than mine. There should be a very strong reason to prefer any regexpless solution to `String#scan`-based one.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over every char and check if char.to_i is the same as char, if so map it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one too

```
str = "12abc3 def*40"

str.each_char do |b|
  puts b unless b.ord > 57 or b.ord < 48
end
```

or

```
str.chars { |b| puts b unless b.ord > 57 or b.ord < 48 }
```

Both are same

result

```
1
2
3
4
0
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend the use of `String#scan`:

```
str = "12abc3 def*40"

str.scan(/\d+/)
#=> ["12", "3", "40"]

str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
#=> [12, 3, 40]
```

It uses a regex but regexes are exactly the right tool for the task at hand.

Comment: but OP opted not use REGEXP

Comment: I guess he wanted not to use the regex because his code became unnecessarily complex. I was however trying to present a simple alternative which, in my opinion, is the best solution to the problem. There is no reason not to use a regex when you are searching a string. Regexes are built to do exactly that.

Comment: I couldnt agree more with you. However, the OP's title said without REGEXP, thats why I commented that. But yeah, I have used scan(/d+/) all the times. Cool

Comment: Sometimes you need to read between the lines to provide a good answer. It happens very frequently that people ask the 'wrong' questions, for example because they got frustrated with their own approach and feel that they their approach is entirely wrong. But often times that's not the case!