# Is there any special meaning of _ in Ruby and why do you use it

Tags: ruby

I have seen a couple of times using `_` in Ruby.

I am not aware of any special meaning of `_` in Ruby. But why and when do you use it?

```
results = votes.map do |vote|
  popu_cost.find(-> {[]}) { |_, cost| cost <= vote }.first
end
```

Or

```
votes.each do |e|
  key, _ = popu_cost.find { |_, val| e >= val }
  results << key if key
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and how is the \_ (underscore) variable specified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` is called unused variable, which wouldn't produce any warning, if you don't use them any where else. Any variable name start with `_`, is called unused variable.

Suppose you have code in `test.rb` file :

```
x = 12
```

Now run the code :

```
$ ruby -w test.rb
test.rb:1: warning: assigned but unused variable - x
$
```

But now change the code too below :

```
_x = 12
```

And now run it again, you wouldn't see any warning :

```
$ ruby -w test.rb
$
```

But you wouldn't see this warning, if you don't run the script with `-w` option.

Comment: just for tips. In `IRB` the last expression is in `_` .

Comment: @Monk_Code Humm.. Correct.