# Merge two hashes together and performing computation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, enumerable

I am attempting to combine two hashes together, and am having trouble figuring out the best method to do it. I feel like there must be an easy way to do it with enumerables...

I'd like to turn this:

```
[{ id: 5, count: 10 }, { id: 6, count: -3 }, { id: 5, count: -2 }, { id: 3, count: 4}]
```

into this:

```
[{ id: 5, count: 8 }, { id: 6, count: -3 }, { id: 3, count: 4}]
```

So that hashes with the same "id" are summed together. Anyone have any ideas on how to quickly do this?

I tried Hash.merge but that didn't work correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way :

```
hash = [{ id: 5, count: 10 }, { id: 6, count: -3 }, { id: 5, count: -2 }, { id: 3, count: 4}]
merged_hash = hash.group_by { |h| h[:id] }.map do |_,v|
  v.reduce do |h1,h2| 
    h1.merge(h2) { |k,o,n| k == :count ? o + n : o }
  end
end

merged_hash 
# => [{:id=>5, :count=>8}, {:id=>6, :count=>-3}, {:id=>3, :count=>4}]
```

Look at these methods [`Hash#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge), [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) and [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Comment: Cool. That works. Question: what is the underscore in the map function do? I realize it's generally key, value

Comment: @BrianW That's also a variable. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified). You will use it, when a value of a variable, you will not use but you have to assign it. This will not create any warning, but if I use like `key`, `k` etc and don't use it any where in my program, that program will raise warning like *assigned but unused variable*.