# Does a variable like /dev/null exist ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, null

Sometime I need to assign a variable which shall never be used. For example:

```
stdin, stdout, status = Open3.capture3("ls ./dir")
```

In this case I'm only interested in the `stdout`, so I won't need `stdin` and `status`. Hi can I prevent the assignment of unused variables in such a case>

Should I do something like?:

```
null, stdout, null = Open3.capture3("ls ./dir")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `capture3` returns stdout, stderr and status.

Comment: Thanks, borrowed the code from http://blog.honeybadger.io/capturing-stdout-stderr-from-shell-commands-via-ruby/

Answer (score 2):

Underscore is normally used in such scenarios

```
_, stdout, _ = Open3.capture3("ls ./dir")
```

Comment: This SO question has more information on the use of _ as a variable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified

Comment: That's true, but I didn't knew I was looking for `_`.

Answer (score 2):

`Open3.capture3` returns an instance of `Array`. You can use destructuring and treat it as a **tuple**, (which is common) or you can treat the result as an actual array:

```
stdout = Open3.capture3("ls ./dir")[1]
```

**It's not idiomatic.**

[Rubocop suggests](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/lint/useless_assignment.rb#L52) preceding unused variable names with `_` in multiple assignments:

```
_stdin, stdout, _status = Open3.capture3("ls ./dir")
```

*NB: as noted above by @Stefan, the second stream returned by `capture3` is actually `stderr`.*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
_, stdout, _ = Open3.capture3("ls ./dir")
```