# How can I assign a value to a void variable using ruby’s multiple assignment?

Tags: ruby, null, variable-assignment, assign, assignment-operator

I would like to use multiple assignment but I don’t care about some part of the values I have in input. So is there a way to assign something to a void variable (aka `/dev/null` from bash) ? something like `nil = 'I wont be used'`. I have a more specific example of what I want to achieve below.

My input is :

```
['no','foo','nop','not at all','bar']
```

And I assign it this way :

```
i,foo,dont,care,bar = ['no','foo','nop','not at all','bar']
#or with a splat :
dont,foo,*care,bar = ['no','foo','nop','not at all','bar']
```

What I would like to do is something like this :

```
nil,foo,*nil,bar = ['no','foo','nop','not at all','bar']
```

Comment: An common alternative is just use `_` as a placeholder var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_, foo, *_, bar = ['no','foo','nop','not at all','bar']
foo #=> "foo"
bar #=> "bar"
_ #=> ["nop", "not at all"]
```

You could also replace `*_` with just `*`.

Yes, `_` is a perfectly valid local variable.

Of course, you don't have to use `_` for the values you won't be using. For example, you could write

```
cat, foo, *dog, bar = ['no','foo','nop','not at all','bar']
```

Using `_` may reduce the chance of errors, but mainly it's for telling the reader that you are not going to use that value. Some prefer using a variable name that begins with an underscore for values that won't be used:

```
_key, value = [1, 2]
```

If you assign fewer variables that there are elements of the array, the elements at the end of the array are discarded. For example,

```
a, b = [1, 2, 3]
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
```

Comment: My advice is to play around with different expressions to see what you get. The basic rule is that if one can conclude that there is only one assignment of values to variable, it's OK. `*a, b, *c = [1,2,3,4,5]` is an example where the assignments are ambiguous, causing Ruby to raise an exception.

Comment: My linter remove the _unused variable_ flag if I write `_` or even if I write `_some_random_name`, is there a convention about it ?

Comment: @UlysseBN, I don't follow "linter", but, yes, some write `_unused_key`. I edited my answer to mention that. Thanks.

Comment: by linter I ment some tool for syntax analysis ([here is the one I use for ruby](https://atom.io/packages/linter-ruby))

Comment: ["Where and how is the _ (underscore) variable specified?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified): from Ruby 2.0, variables starting with underscore have special handling that prevents certain warnings and errors consistent with "I don't care about this value" semantics (and before that, only `_` itself did). For example, `def x(a, a, c)` is invalid, but `def x(_, _, c)` is valid; `def x(_a, _a, c)` is valid since 2.0 AFAIK. It's not just linter opinion, the linter is actually following Ruby's rules.

Comment: That's a good point, @Amadan, but note that it does not apply to parallel assignment: `a,b,a = [1,2,3]; a #=> 3; b #=> 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-values_at) to extract certain elements from the array:

```
ary = ['no','foo','nop','not at all','bar']

foo, bar = ary.values_at(1, -1)

foo #=> "foo"
bar #=> "bar"
```

Besides indices, it also accepts ranges:

```
ary.values_at(0, 2..3) #=> ["no", "nop", "not at all"]
```