# Drop value in parallel assignment

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

Since parallel assignment like this can be done,

```
x, y, z = [1, 2, 3]
```

I wanted to know if one could drop for example the `y` value. Is there a way of doing parallel assignment without polluting the namespace of the current scope?

I tried assigning to `nil`:

```
x, nil, z = [1, 2, 3]
```

but that does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do that is to assign it to variable named underscore:

```
x, _, z = [1, 2, 3]
```

If there are multiple values that you want to drop, you can use splat:

```
x, *_, z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: For multiple values, `*` is enough. Or, to be explicit about the number of variables being thrown out, `_` has a special syntax such that it can be repeated in assignment. `x, _, _, _, z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: @sawa, good point on the single `*`. I will not edit my answer so that I don't obsolete AKovtunov's. As for the multiple `_`s - it depends more on what you are trying to say IMO. Are you trying to say that `z` is the last element or the 5th element?

Comment: @sawa: There's nothing special about `_` AFAIK. `x, y, y, y, z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is a valid but confusing syntax. `y` is set to `4`

Comment: @EricDuminil, underscored names are a little bit special. You can't define a method with repeating parameter names, unless they start with `_`. Same goes for block parameters. But indeed, not in this case.

Comment: It's interesting to see how duplicate questions often bring many upvotes. I've had a nice answer badge for "3/2 is 1, not 1.5" :). Anyway, you'll soon get your Ruby golden badge. ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil Oops. You are right. Sorry about that. My knowledge must be outdated. I remember `_` used to be the only variable allowed to do that. Perhaps they changed it at some point.

Comment: @sawa: No problem, I wasn't sure either and learned something. `a, a = 1` is a confusing way to set `a` to `nil` :)

Comment: @EricDuminil, don't know about duplicate questions, but very basic ones - indeed, it's frustrating. At least in the short term, the main indicator on how many upvotes a post will get is how many people are going to read and understand it. It's one of the downfalls of SO's gamification system. :/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: Variables starting with `_` (including `_` itself) don't generate a "unused variable" warning.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @ndn, `_` is often used.

It's okay to ignore it and to reassign over it, but `_` is still a variable in the namespace of the current scope :

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

x, _, z = l
puts _
#=> 2
```

If it bothers you, you could use :

```
x, z = l.values_at(0,-1)
```

It might be less readable though. `_` is also the proposed syntax if you launch `rubocop` on the script.

Talking about readability, if you want to explain what the variable is, but still want to show that it won't be used afterwards, you could use :

```
x, _y, z = [1, 2, 3]
# Do something with x and z. Ignore _y
```

It's also proposed by rubocop :

```
test.rb:2:4: W: Useless assignment to variable - y. Use _ or _y as a variable name to indicate that it won't be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

meschi has asked whether it is possible, using parallel assignment, to assign some, but not all, elements of an array to variables.

Firstly, it doesn't help to write

```
a, _, c = [1, true, 2]
```

since `_` is a variable:

```
_ #=> true
```

(You won't get this result using IRB as IRB uses `_` for its own purposes.)

If, in the above array, you only want to assign `1` and `true` to variables you can write

```
a, b, * = [1, true, 2]
a #=> 1
b #=> true
```

If you only want to assign `1` and `2` to variables, you can write

```
a, *, b = [1, true, 2]
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
```

If, for the array `[1, true, 2, 3]`, you wish to assign only `1` and `2` to variables, well, that's a problem. Evidently, as @Eric pointed out in a comment, you'd need to write

```
a, b, b, * = [1, true, 2, 3]
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
```

This idea can of course be generalized:

```
a, b, b, b, c, c = [1, true, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a #=> 1
b #=> 3
c #=> 5
```

Is this a good idea? That was not the question.

The main concern may be creating a not-to-be-used variable and then inadvertently using it, as here:

```
a, _, b = [1, true, 2]
...
launch_missiles_now?(_)
```

If so, there are a few options. One is to simply wrap the expression in an method, thereby keeping the superfluous variables tightly-confined:

```
def get_a_and_b(arr)
  a, _, b, _ = arr
  [a, b]
end

a, b = get_a_and_b [1, true, 2, 3]
  #=> [1, 2]
```

Another is to name unwanted variables to make it unlikely that they will referenced accidentally, for example:

```
a, _reference_this_variable_and_you_will_die, b = [1, true, 2]
```

Answer (score -2):

I would prefer to improve @ndn answer and use only `*` symbol to drop values. 
`_` usually used to return last value, so it can be confusing to use it here.

So you can use

```
x, *, z = [1, 2, 3]
```

as well as

```
x, *, y, z = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and it will still understand you and return the proper values for all the variables.

Comment: `*` implies that arbitrary number of variables are assigned here as a single array. If you specifically know that there is only single term, then `_` is more specific, and hence more preferable.

Comment: "`_` [is] usually used to return [the] last value, so it can be confusing to use it here."--What is your basis for this? As far as I know, that is wrong.

Comment: I also would like to know where `_ usually used to return last value` comes from

Comment: @sawa @andrey-deineko I can't find any good documentation for underscore variable to prove my thoughts, but discussions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559561/where-and-how-is-the-underscore-variable-specified (beginning of the question) shows that a lot of people use underscore as a `last value`. Also it's described as a predefined value for the last value from ruby docs https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/variable.html#uscore

Comment: `_` means the last value in IRB and PRY. It means "ignore me" in every ruby script, though. You can even use `__` for second to last in PRY.

Comment: Don't confuse a command in Pry or IRB with Ruby syntax. They're very different things.

Comment: @theTinMan I think ruby manual covers not only Pry\IRB https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/variable.html#uscore :)

Comment: You appear to be confusing `$_` and `_`. They are not the same. `$_` is a global containing the last line read from the console or when reading a file line-by-line. `_` is a "slush" or "blackhole" variable we use when we mean to throw a value away. You are arguing a point that is being contradicted by experienced Ruby programmers.