# {|_, e| e.length>1} what is the use of underScore ( _ ) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
country =
  ["UK", "US", "RS", "EU", "UK", "US"].
    group_by{ |e| e }.
    keep_if{ |_, e | e.length > 1 }
#⇒ {"UK"=>["UK", "UK"], "US"=>["US", "US"]}
```

What is the use of `_` (underscore) in the second block. Can someone explain in details?

Comment: Related but not quite a duplicate: [**Where and how is the _ (underscore) variable specified?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9559561/479863)

Answer (score 11):

There are three answers to this on two levels.

The first answer is on the level of the Ruby language: there is no use of the underscore in Ruby. It has no meaning. It is just a legal identifier like any other legal identifier. It could have been named `foo` or `bar` instead, and it would not in any way change the meaning of this code.

The second answer is on the level of the Ruby community: in the Ruby community, the underscore is used to communicate to other programmers reading the code "I need to put an identifier here because the rules of the Ruby language force me to, but I am not actually interested in it, I will in fact never use it." So, it has no meaning to Ruby, but it *does* have meaning to Ruby *programmers*. It's just like methods ending in `!` or `?`: they have no special meaning, they are just used to communicate intent from one Ruby programmer to another.

The third answer is again on the level of the Ruby language: because of #2, there were two changes made in Ruby 1.9+ that codify the uses of the underscore as an "ignore me" identifier:

1. Normally, unused local variables generate warnings. Unused local variables that start with an underscore, or are simply named `_` do not generate warnings.
2. Normally, an identifier can only be used once in a parameter list. Identifiers that start with an underscore, or are simply named `_` can be used multiple times.

See:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

foo = nil
bar = nil
baz = nil
```

Running:

```
./test.rb
./test.rb:3: warning: assigned but unused variable - foo
./test.rb:4: warning: assigned but unused variable - bar
./test.rb:5: warning: assigned but unused variable - baz
```

But:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

_foo = nil
_bar = nil
_    = nil
```

Running:

```
./test.rb
```

And:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

def foo(bar, bar) end
```

Running:

```
./test.rb
./test.rb:3: duplicated argument name
def foo(bar, bar); end
```

[The second `bar` is underlined in the console, which is hard to reproduce here.]

But:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

def foo(_bar, _bar) end
```

Running:

```
./test.rb
```

So, the only difference between an underscore and no underscore is that the underscore turns off certain errors and warnings, in line with its common usage within the Ruby community.

This convention is generally also respected by linters, static analyzers, editors, and IDEs providing semantic analysis of Ruby code, e.g. IDEs that highlight and warn about unused variables will not do so for variables whose name begins with or is `_`.

Comment: It's worth noting that some editors, like Visual Studio Code, will highlight "unused" variables differently to point out this condition, and also respect the underscore prefix.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I added a paragraph at the end,

Answer (score 5):

By convention, underscore is used as a variable name for a value that is not used. Unlike other variable names, it can be used multiple times in a single parallel assignment.

In this particular case, the filter in the block is not interested in the key of the hash, but only the value of the hash, which is an array generated by `group_by`.

Comment: A small point: a variation of the convention is to write a variable name that begins with an underscore. For example, if `h` we're a hash, `h.each { |_k, v| .. }` would signal to the reader that the hash's keys are not used in the block calculation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am not sure if that is popular. I often use `_a` to indicate elements of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

In IRB/Pry console this variable is used as *last returned value*. There could be interesting cases beyond just being a placeholder, like:

```rb
1
_ + 2
_ * 3
_.to_f / 2
```

which returns:

```
1
=> 1
_ + 2
=> 3
_ * 3
=> 9
_.to_f / 2
=> 4.5
```

or

```rb
[:flowers]
_ << :leaves
```

which results in:

```
[:flowers]
=> [:flowers]
_ << :leaves
=> [:flowers, :leaves]
```

You can use it for variables/classes/methods basically `_` contains the result of previous line you types, this is very convenient when called some `LongRunning.method` while in console and forgot to assign to a variable like `result = ...` for later inspection, so you can just type `result = _` or simply `_` and assign your data to the variable.