# What does the underscore in this particular code do?

Tags: ruby

I'm confused to as what the underscore's purpose is in this code.

```rb
def unmatched_pos    
    (pos, _) = @known_cards.find do |pos, val|
      @known_cards.any? do |pos2, val2|
        (pos != pos2 && val == val2) &&
          !(@matched_cards[pos] || @matched_cards[pos2])
      end
    end

    pos
end
```

Comment: [This](https://genua.github.io/ruby/2015/03/04/underscores-ampersands-asterisks/) could help

Answer (score 3):

Underscores are placeholders for variables that you don't use.

Since you only need the position, you "drop" the val. You could also use `_value` instead of just `_` to indicate that you don't need the variable but still name it something more useful than just `_`.

Answer (score 2):

You cand the answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55305492/9567450, _ is used as a variable when the value is never used

Answer (score 1):

It's just a placeholder for the second return value. It says: "I know a second value is returned but I'm not interested in it."